# flask - Why url of an image is not identical to its actual path?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using `flask.send_file` to send images to my client.

However, when I was trying to get the url of a image using `url_for`, I found the result returned is not the same with the image's path.

```
def get(self):
        print url_for('static', filename='test.jpg')
        filename = 'static/img/test.jpg'
        return send_file(filename)
```

I got

> /static/test.jpg

in the console.

The file structure is

```
└── static
    └── img
        └── test.jpg
```

Why the url is not **`/static/img/test.jpg`**?

### EDIT

And when I request from the browser, the code above works well. On the contrast, the browser return error if I change the filename to `static/test.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've told it to print the URL for "test.jpg" inside "static". Since you haven't included any reference to "img", there's no way that url_for can include it.

Note that this has nothing to do with the actual URL you return from the function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't quite understand what does `include any reference to "img"` mean. So the `url_for` method would automatically ignore the child directory inside it?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all, and I can't understand your confusion. You are printing the result of `url_for` when you pass it just "static" and "test.jpg". All that function does is create a URL from those two values. It doesn't know or care anything about your actual directory structure. It also has *nothing* to do with the actual URL you are returning from that method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should give `url_for` the full path to your image **relative** to the static folder.
So I think in your case it would be

url_for('static', filename='img/test.jpg')

url_for will just concatenate the path you give it to the static folder path, so to generate a URI to that file, but it won't magically map or guess the location of your files.

Comment: I think I haven't express clearly so that you've got a misunderstanding. See my edit please.